# Issue in converting float to currency String formatter

Tags: ios, swift, numberformatter

Extenstion for converter Swift 4.2

```
extension Float {
    var localeCurrency: String {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .currency
        formatter.locale = .current
        return formatter.string(from: self as NSNumber)!
    }
}
```

Accessing the value

```
 let   amount = 200.02
    print("Amount Saved Value ",String(format:"%.2f", amountSaving. localeCurrency))
```

For me Its return 0.00!
Looks to me Extenstion Perfect when accessing it return 0.00! Why?

Comment: `amountSaving.localeCurrency` is returning a `String`, but you're trying to format it as a floating value, `String(format:"%.2f", ...` which doesn't make sense, why not just use the result of `localeCurrency`? `print("Amount Saved Value \(amountSaving.localeCurrency)")`?

Comment: @MadProgrammer Oops!   Thanks really really helps.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Why float variable and int variable unable to multiple ? I have to forcefully need to tap cast Int variable into Float.  Any comments!

Comment: That's how Swift works, `Int` and `Float` are not "primitive" types, but constructs of the concept - not entirely familiar with the inner works myself though

Comment: @MadProgrammer My knowledge Int and float are primitive type (like Bool,byte,short,double too)!

Comment: `public struct Int : FixedWidthInteger, SignedInteger {` would suggest they are not (cmd+click on `Int` and select "Jump to definition") - I believe that this is a deliberate design choice

Comment: You could also have a look at things like the [documentation for Swift `Int`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/int) which shows that it's a `struct`

Comment: @MadProgrammer Yeap you are correct! I have to remove the java concepts out of swift place.

Comment:  welcome to my world